# sp_executesql failing if line ends in \

Tags: sql, t-sql

This code:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[a]
(
@VarA NVARCHAR(200), -- Path to exe e.g. e:\blah\blah\
@VarB INT -- 1 to log actions
)
AS
BEGIN
PRINT @VarA
PRINT @VarB
END'
GO
```

That'll throw an error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure a, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure a, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the scalar variable "@VarB".
```

If you remove the \ so have e:\blah\blah instead it works; if you add a space after the \ it works - it all seems to be to do with that ...

So - is that a bug?

Thanks, Dr. Michael Dye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using the [Backslash (Line Continuation) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-backslash?view=sql-server-ver15) feature. This means that the lines below:

```
(
@VarA NVARCHAR(200), -- Path to exe e.g. e:\blah\blah\
@VarB INT -- 1 to log actions
)
```

Are being parsed as

```
(
@VarA NVARCHAR(200), -- Path to exe e.g. e:\blah\blah\@VarB INT -- 1 to log actions
)
```

As a result, the error.

Therefore, don't end you're line with a `\` and then immediately preceed it with a line break or carriage return and line break. As this is a comment, you could simply put a `.` at the end:

```
(
@VarA NVARCHAR(200), -- Path to exe e.g. e:\blah\blah\.
@VarB INT -- 1 to log actions
)
```

Comment: I honestly only learned about this feature earlier this week, @MichaelDye .